# Setting position of custom slider controls (CSS)

Tags: html, css, web, frontend, w3c

I've been making my anime website where people can watch anime for free with subtitles (Bulgarian subtitles, since I'm from Bulgaria). Now I'm remaking it from scratch because I have been using a theme but It didn't have much functionality... Now I'm making the slider for the recently added animes but I want it to be a custom one so I'm making.... the slider controls are not in a position, so I tried with float, flex with float, etc.... Here's a picture where it should belong: [click to open the image (important)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W22mS.png)

Here's the HTML:

```
        <div class="recent-anime">
      <!-- Title and Controls -->
      <div class="title-controls">
        <h1 class="title">Наскоро добавни</h1>
        <a><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></a>
        <a><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
      </div>
      <!-- Anime cards -->
      <div class="animecards">

        <div class="animecard">
          <img src="images/cover.png">

          <div class="ani">
            <p class="anititle">Anime title</p>
            <p class="aniepisode">Episode</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="animecard ml">
          <img src="images/cover.png">

          <div class="ani">
            <p class="anititle">Anime title</p>
            <p class="aniepisode">Episode</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="animecard ml">
          <img src="images/cover.png">

          <div class="ani">
            <p class="anititle">Anime title</p>
            <p class="aniepisode">Episode</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="animecard ml">
          <img src="images/cover.png">

          <div class="ani">
            <p class="anititle">Anime title</p>
            <p class="aniepisode">Episode</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="animecard ml">
          <img src="images/cover.png">

          <div class="ani">
            <p class="anititle">Anime title</p>
            <p class="aniepisode">Episode</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="animecard ml">
          <img src="images/cover.png">

          <div class="ani">
            <p class="anititle">Anime title</p>
            <p class="aniepisode">Episode</p>
          </div>
        </div>  

      </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.title-controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.title {
  font-size: 26px;
}

.animecards {
  display: flex;
}
.animecard {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.animecard img {
  max-height: 325px;
}
.ml {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.ani {
  text-align: center;
}
```

There's no JS. Still on the HTML and CSS part.
NOTE: This is clean CSS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`justify-content: space-between;` on `title-controls` class will solve the issue shown in image

```
.title-controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```